# Django naturaltime() adds strange characters

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding

With Django 1.8.2 when i use naturaltime on a timestamp for some ready the following is the result:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime

naturaltime(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 16, 19, 37, 38, 338598))
'2\xa0days ago'
```

If I downgrade to an earlier Django (e.g. 1.6.2), the result is what I want:

```
'2 days ago'
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Though I am not in proper explanation of why 1.6.2 is failing, because [#20246](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20246) seems to be applied on [1.6.2](https://github.com/django/django/commits/1.6.2/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py) as well. Basically, its the template tag filters and the `\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also chr(160).` (`&nbsp;`). If u want to use in your code, try: `string.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` or decode it with `ascii`

Comment: 1.6.2 isnt failing, 1.8 is. and i'd rather fix the issue at source rather than a dirty replace on the way out

Comment: Sorry, a typo, "I am not in proper explanation of why 1.6.2 is passing" because it should also according to the history of commits should have got the fix for whatever was given on "non-breaking"

Comment: And for the reference of you considering it to a dirty workaround, I guess its not an issue with the code and they have given a fix which is giving you `\xa0`. Read the issue ticket properly